# How do I update bootstrap-table columns from server side response from ajax method? It causes an infinite loop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

My boostrap-table's output (both columns and rows) are derived from a REST API.

I read that the best way to recreate the table with new columns is by using the '[refreshOptions](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#methods/refresh-options.html#view-source)' method. But when I do this inside the 'ajax' method for the table, it goes into an infinite loop - as it looks like it completely destroys the table, rebuilds it and triggers the ajax load again. This causes an infinite recursive loop of ajax calls.

What is an elegant way to recreate the columns based on the response data before loading the rows?

I have created a live example to demonstrate this scenario:
https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/epicwhale/14790

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me.

```
<table
  id="table"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-height="460"
  data-ajax="ajaxRequest"
  data-search="true"
  data-side-pagination="server"
  data-pagination="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<script>
  let new_columns = [{
        title: 'ID_NEW',
        field: 'id'
      }, {
        title: 'Item Name_NEW',
        field: 'name'
      }, {
        title: 'Item Price_NEW',
        field: 'price'
      }]
  
  function ajaxRequest(params) {
    var url = 'https://examples.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/bootstrap_table/data'
    $.get(url + '?' + $.param(params.data)).then(function (res) {
       params.success(res)
    })
  }
    
  var $table = $('#table')
  $(function() {
    $("#table").bootstrapTable('refreshOptions',
     { columns: new_columns });

  })
</script>
```